# android facebook GraphUser is always null

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, fragment

I have problem with code below. I try to log in with facebook to my app, when I use app with Activities this code works, but when I change it to Fragments it's stops work. When I first click on fb button I'm redirect to fb login but when I give username and pass, it doesn't go to onUserInfoFetched metod and doesn't directed me to ScreenFragment, and stay on the first fragment, and when I click the fb login button again in logcat shows me info "NOT_WORK" so user is null. 
Could you help me with this?

```
loginBtn.setReadPermissions(permissions);
loginBtn.setUserInfoChangedCallback(new LoginButton.UserInfoChangedCallback() {
@Override 
public void onUserInfoFetched(GraphUser user) {
            if (user != null) {
                getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().
                        replace(android.R.id.content, new ScreenFragment()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
            } else {
                Log.d("FB", "NOT_WORK");
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Fragments, you need to call

```
loginBtn.setFragment(this);
```

from within your Fragment implementation, and also override the onActivityResult method in your Fragment and pass it to the loginBtn.

Comment: The main problem was that I'm using library Fragment but Facebook requires using android fragments from support library.